# for loops for regression models in r

Tags: r, for-loop, regression, paste

```
library(RSA)

dat<- iris


lm(Petal.Length~Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width, data=dat)
RSA(Petal.Length~Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width, data=dat)

lm(Petal.Width~Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width, data=dat)
RSA(Petal.Width~Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width, data=dat)
```

I am trying to conduct Response surface analysis using RSA package in R.
The above command works well.

However, if I twist a little, it never works although it is the same command.

```
for(i in 3:4){
  

  
  model1 <- lm(paste0(colnames(dat[i]),"~ Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width"), data=dat) # this works 
  model2 <- RSA(paste0(colnames(dat[i]),"~ Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width"), data=dat) # this doesnt
  
  
  out<-list(model1, model2)
  
  print(out)}
```

I don't understand because

```
i=3
RSA(paste0(colnames(dat[i]),"~ Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width"), data=dat) 
 
RSA(Petal.Length~Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width, data=dat)
```

These two command is equivalent while one code works but others does not.

Comment: with the `lm` you do not need the for loop ie `lm(cbind(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)~Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width, data=iris)` should work. I am not sure of RSA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly convert the character string into a formula, e.g.:

```r
f_str <- paste0(colnames(dat[i]),"~ Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width")
try(RSA(f_str, data=dat))
## Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , c(DV, IV1, IV2, control.variables)) : 
## undefined columns selected
RSA(formula(f_str), data=dat)  ## works
```

An equivalent but slightly cleaner version:

```r
RSA(reformulate("Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width", response = names(dat)[i]),
    data = dat)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way.
First create named lists to hold the results. Then, use [`reformulate`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/delete.response.html) to create the regression formulas.

```r
library(RSA)
#> Loading required package: lavaan
#> This is lavaan 0.6-15
#> lavaan is FREE software! Please report any bugs.
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: lattice

dat<- iris

# which responses do we want
petal_names <- grep("Petal", names(dat), value = TRUE)
# lists to hold the regressions' results
lm_list <- setNames(vector("list", length(petal_names)), petal_names)
RSA_list <- setNames(vector("list", length(petal_names)), petal_names)

# run the regressions, the initial message is not
# asked for in the question and can be deleted
for(nm in petal_names) {
  msg <- sprintf("\nResponse: %s", nm)
  message(msg)
  fmla <- reformulate("Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width", nm)
  lm_list[[nm]] <- lm(fmla, data = dat)
  RSA_list[[nm]] <- RSA(fmla, data = dat)
}
#> 
#> Response: Petal.Length
#> Warning in RSA(fmla, data = dat): The numerical zero point is outside of the
#> range of variable Sepal.Length . Please consider re-centering the variable.
#> Warning in RSA(fmla, data = dat): The numerical zero point is outside of the
#> range of variable Sepal.Width . Please consider re-centering the variable.
#> [1] "Computing additive model (additive) ..."
#> [1] "Computing x + x^2 model (onlyx2) ..."
#> [1] "Computing y + y^2 model (onlyy2) ..."
#> [1] "Computing x model (onlyx) ..."
#> [1] "Computing y model (onlyy) ..."
#> [1] "Computing interaction model (IA)..."
#> [1] "Computing squared difference model (SQD) ..."
#> [1] "Computing shifted squared difference model (SSQD) ..."
#> [1] "Computing rising ridge model (RR) ..."
#> [1] "Computing shifted rising ridge model (SRR) ..."
#> [1] "Computing rotated and shifted rising ridge model (SRRR), up ..."
#> [1] "Computing rotated and shifted rising ridge model (SRRR), down ..."
#> [1] "Direction of SRRR curvature: down"
#> [1] "Computing rotated squared difference model (SRSQD), up ..."
#> [1] "Computing rotated squared difference model (SRSQD), down ..."
#> [1] "Direction of SRSQD curvature: down"
#> [1] "Computing polynomial model (full) ..."
#> 
#> Response: Petal.Width
#> Warning in RSA(fmla, data = dat): The numerical zero point is outside of the
#> range of variable Sepal.Length . Please consider re-centering the variable.

#> Warning in RSA(fmla, data = dat): The numerical zero point is outside of the
#> range of variable Sepal.Width . Please consider re-centering the variable.
#> [1] "Computing additive model (additive) ..."
#> [1] "Computing x + x^2 model (onlyx2) ..."
#> [1] "Computing y + y^2 model (onlyy2) ..."
#> [1] "Computing x model (onlyx) ..."
#> [1] "Computing y model (onlyy) ..."
#> [1] "Computing interaction model (IA)..."
#> [1] "Computing squared difference model (SQD) ..."
#> [1] "Computing shifted squared difference model (SSQD) ..."
#> [1] "Computing rising ridge model (RR) ..."
#> [1] "Computing shifted rising ridge model (SRR) ..."
#> [1] "Computing rotated and shifted rising ridge model (SRRR), up ..."
#> [1] "Computing rotated and shifted rising ridge model (SRRR), down ..."
#> [1] "Direction of SRRR curvature: down"
#> [1] "Computing rotated squared difference model (SRSQD), up ..."
#> [1] "Computing rotated squared difference model (SRSQD), down ..."
#> [1] "Direction of SRSQD curvature: down"
#> [1] "Computing polynomial model (full) ..."

# see some of the results
lm_list$Petal.Length
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = fmla, data = dat)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              (Intercept)              Sepal.Length               Sepal.Width  
#>                   6.3910                    0.2042                   -4.1994  
#> Sepal.Length:Sepal.Width  
#>                   0.5057
RSA_list$Petal.Length
#> No model has been specified - showing results for the full second-order polynomial model (<full>).
#> RSA output (package version 0.10.6)
#> ===========================================
#> 
#> Are there discrepancies in the predictors (with respect to numerical congruence)?
#> (A cutpoint of |Δz| > 0.5 is used)
#> 
#> ----------------------------
#> Sepal.Width < Sepal.Length                  congruent 
#>                     "100%"                       "0%" 
#> Sepal.Width > Sepal.Length 
#>                       "0%" 
#> 
#> Is the corresponding global model (full second-order polynomial model) significant?
#> ----------------------------
#> Test on model significance: R^2 = 0.894, p <.001
#> 
#> 
#> Number of observations: n = 150
#> ----------------------------
#> 
#> 
#> Regression coefficients for model <full>
#> ----------------------------
#>                                       label    est    se ci.lower ci.upper
#> Petal.Length~1                           b0 -5.323 3.454  -12.092    1.447
#> Petal.Length~Sepal.Length                b1  2.740 0.731    1.307    4.173
#> Petal.Length~Sepal.Width                 b2 -1.438 1.202   -3.794    0.918
#> Petal.Length~Sepal.Length2               b3 -0.261 0.057   -0.372   -0.150
#> Petal.Length~Sepal.Length_Sepal.Width    b4  0.685 0.150    0.391    0.978
#> Petal.Length~Sepal.Width2                b5 -0.593 0.162   -0.910   -0.276
#>                                         beta   pvalue sig
#> Petal.Length~1                        -3.025 p = .123    
#> Petal.Length~Sepal.Length              1.285  p <.001 ***
#> Petal.Length~Sepal.Width              -0.355 p = .232    
#> Petal.Length~Sepal.Length2            -1.466  p <.001 ***
#> Petal.Length~Sepal.Length_Sepal.Width  1.304  p <.001 ***
#> Petal.Length~Sepal.Width2             -0.920  p <.001 ***
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> Surface tests (a1 to a5) for model <full>
#> ----------------------------
#>   label    est    se ci.lower ci.upper   pvalue sig
#> 1    a1  1.302 1.644   -1.920    4.523 p = .428    
#> 2    a2 -0.169 0.206   -0.573    0.236 p = .413    
#> 3    a3  4.178 1.121    1.980    6.376  p <.001 ***
#> 4    a4 -1.539 0.265   -2.057   -1.020  p <.001 ***
#> 5    a5  0.332 0.158    0.022    0.642 p = .036   *
#> 
#> a1: Linear additive effect on line of congruence? NO
#> a2: Is there curvature on the line of congruence? NO
#> a3: Is the ridge shifted away from the LOC? YES
#> a4: Is there curvature on the line of incongruence? YES
#> 
#> 
#> Location of stationary point for model <full>
#> ----------------------------
#> Sepal.Length = 15.129; Sepal.Width = 7.525; predicted Petal.Length = 9.993
#> 
#> 
#> Principal axes for model <full>
#> ----------------------------
#>                    label    est     se ci.lower ci.upper   pvalue sig
#> Intercept of 1. PA   p10 -1.953  1.099   -4.107    0.200 p = .075   †
#> Slope of 1. PA       p11  0.626  0.138    0.357    0.896  p <.001 ***
#> Intercept of 2. PA   p20 31.676 28.258  -23.708   87.059 p = .262    
#> Slope of 2. PA       p21 -1.596  0.351   -2.284   -0.908  p <.001 ***
#>   --> Lateral shift of first PA from LOC at point (0; 0): C1 =  1.201 
#>   --> Lateral shift of second PA from LOC at point (0; 0): C2 =  53.122
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

A simpler way is to run two `*apply` loops, one to create the formulas, the other to fit the models. The output will be a named list of named lists, for each response and for each fitting function.

```
petal_names <- grep("Petal", names(dat), value = TRUE)
fmla_list <- sapply(petal_names, reformulate, termlabels = "Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width")
models_list <- lapply(fmla_list, \(fmla) {
  list(lm = lm(fmla, data = dat), RSA = RSA(fmla, data = dat))
})

models_list$Petal.Length$lm
models_list$Petal.Length$RSA

models_list$Petal.Width$lm
models_list$Petal.Width$RSA
```